# Create a composite foreign key in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a foreign key over two fields with the visual editor.

TabA: (idA, idB) <- idB is the primary key, (idA,idB) is unique

TabB: (id, idA, idB) <- id is primary key, (idA,idB) has an index not null

I can connect both tables in the visual editor. But when I set on the referential integrity, I get the error: "There is no unique index for the referenced field in the primary table" (translated from german).

Where is the problem?

Edit:

I finally found out that I was using the editor in the wrong way. My fault, that I start draging the fields from the wrong table. If I do right, everything works as expected.

I am not sure, if I will delete the question.

Comment: Can you post a quick screenshot of those indexes so I can verify you have indeed created a unique composite index? And a screenshot of the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

> TabA: (idA, idB) <- idB is the primary key, (idA,idB) is unique

But that won't work. Either use idB as the foreign key in the child table, or assign (idA, idB) as the primary key in TabA (*bad* idea).

By the way, when defining RI, Access will automatically create the unique index for the foreign key on the child table. It will, however, be hidden. But you don't have create it manually.

Comment: 1) That means, I can use a single (not pk) field as foreign key, but not a combination of fields? 2) What means "be hidden"? I can't see the index in die indicies windows of the visual designer?

Comment: 1. The only FK, you can use, is one that matches the PK of the parent table. 2. Yes, not listed in the GUI. But you can list them all (and their attributes) using VBA.